# Encode data to HEX and get an L at the end in Python 2.7. Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I ask a Measurement Device to give me some Data. At first it tells me how many bytes of data are in the storage. It is always 14. Then it gives me the data which i have to encode into hex. It is Python 2.7 can´t use newer versions. Line 6 to 10 tells the Device to give me the measured data.
Line 12 to 14 is the encoding to Hex. In other Programs it works. but when i print result(Line 14) then i get a Hex number with 13 Bytes PLUS 1 which can not be correct because it has an L et the end. I guess it is some LONG or whatever. and i dont need the last Byte. but i do think it changes the Data too, which is picked out from Line 15 and up. at first in Hex. Then it is converted into Int.

Is it possible that the L has an effect on the Data or not?
How can i fix it?

```
1       ap.write(b"ML\0")
        rmemb = ap.read(2)
        print(rmemb)
        rmemb = int(rmemb)+1
5       rmem = rmemb          #must be and is 14 Bytes

        addmem = ("MR:%s\0" % rmem)
   #    addmem = ("MR:14\0")
        ap.write(addmem.encode())
10      time.sleep(1)

        test = ap.read(rmem)
        result = hex(int(test.encode('hex'), 16))
        print(result)
15      ftflash = result[12:20]
        ftbg = result[20:28]
        print(ftflash)
        print(ftbg)
        ftflash = int(ftflash, 16)
20 #    print(ftflash)
        ftbg = int(ftbg, 16)
   #    print(ftbg)
```

OUTPUT:

```
14
0x11bd5084c0b000001ce00000093L
b000001c
e0000009
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2 has two built-in integer types, `int` and `long`. `hex` returns a string representing a Python hexadecimal literal, and in Python 2, that means that `long`s get an `L` at the end, to signify that it's a `long`.

Comment: And why does it delete the last databyte. because the HEX number contains 27 Numbers and the L. shouldnt it be 28 and L?

Comment: @Dibsi: It's giving you a hex representation of a number, not of a byte sequence. That means no leading zeros. If you didn't want that, then don't do that weird hex-to-integer-and-back-to-hex conversion.

Comment: ah thank you. this was the first helpful answer i have received. Have a nice day